# Why Unity3d takes so long time to "rebuild" when I change build platform?

Tags: unity

I would like to know what happens "behind the scenes" when I change my unity game target platform .

If I switch from Android to iOS or Pc or etc, Unity rebuild something and takes a lot of hours to complete.

What is the reason ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the target platform is changed, Unity has to (re)import the asset data for all your assets, since that data is platform-dependent. The process can take a long time if the project has many assets (although I'd say "*a lot of hours*" is really extreme, unless the computer is really slow).

If you want to accelerate the process you can use Unity's [Cache Server](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CacheServer.html), which, as its name implies, caches the data of the assets and allows Unity to just download it when needed instead of recreating it, and it's much faster. It works fine as a server in the local computer, no need for a dedicated server in the network.